# Formatting output in C#

Tags: c#, get, position

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            SerialPort sp = new SerialPort();
            sp.PortName = "COM1";
            sp.BaudRate = 9600;
            sp.Open();

            if (sp.IsOpen)
            {
                sp.Write("ENA;");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);

                sp.Write("POS;");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);                    
                string msgPos = sp.ReadExisting();

                Console.WriteLine(msgPos);

                sp.Write("OFF;");
                sp.Close();
                Console.ReadKey();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Above is code for taking current position of stepper motor. under is link to my output. But I cant format it to numbers.

Here is: [Manual controler for stepper motor (page 28)](http://driver232.rozek.sk/UIM241.pdf)

Here is output: [Picture of my output](http://mix.rozek.sk/output.jpg)

Comment: Ask the stepper motor SDK vendor. There is no way anyone else can tell. Perhaps they can if you explain what `sp` is, what SDK / API you use and what manual came with the motor.

Comment: Huh, huh, huh... (Beavis and Butthead style) `POS`... :-) On a more serious note what and where is `sp`? Some StreamReader? Are you using a library and what library is it? We need more code please.

Answer (score 4):

You're hugely over-estimating the speed of the serial port;

```
sp.Write("POS;");                 // Writes the data to the serial port
string msg = sp.ReadExisting();   // Immediately reads already available data
```

> [ReadExisting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readexisting.aspx): Reads all immediately available bytes, based on the encoding, in both the stream and the input buffer of the SerialPort object.

When you're calling `ReadExisting`, it will immediately return with the data that is *already available in the serial port buffers*, probably far before the connected device even received the `POS` command.